# Excepted output not getting?

Tags: python, function, factorial

```
def factorial(n,fact):
    if n!=0:
        fact=fact*n
        factorial(n-1,fact)
    else:
        print(fact)
        return fact
print(factorial(5,1))
```

I have done factorial program.but when I am printing it gets 120 but when I am returning it saying none
When I am using both i am get only 120.it is not getting 2 120 in my output what go wrong could you explain it. Why it returning none is my question why not 120.

I am not get 120 120.it getting only 120 and none I am getting.why I am getting none.could you explain it to me

Comment: you need to return `factorial(n-1,fact)` also

Comment: If `n` is non-zero, you don't return anything.  See the documentation for the `return` statement.  If a function reaches the end without executing an explicit return, it implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Either `print` in the function, or `print` the return, but not both.  As a general rule, a function like this should ONLY return its values, and let the caller decide what to do with it.  Don't `print` in a utility function (except for debugging).